# htaccess not rewriting URL when directory without index.php is fetched

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have written an htaccess file to rewrite URLs. What it should do: when the user visits a URL for which there is no corresponding PHP file, it redirects to route.php.

It got a bit complicated for the case of directories; if there's no index.php in the directory navigated to, it should rewrite to route.php too.

Here's the code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if it's a directory without an index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . route.php [L]

# Check if it's not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . route.php [L]
```

The problem is, when I nagivate to '/' where there is no index.php, it (unwantedly) shows a directory listing (or "Forbidden" if indexes are disabled).

What is going on? How can I make it rewrite requests to a directory for which there is no index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct but there is a dot in first `RewriteRule` which means at least one character has to be present in URI. However for landing page relative URI will be just an empty string.

This should work for you:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Check if it's a directory without an index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^ route.php [L]

# Check if it's not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ route.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This got an answer that should work already, but for completeness sake I want to point out an alternative.

> if there's no index.php in the directory navigated to, it should rewrite to route.php too

You don't necessarily *need* to use rewriting for that, you can specify this as an alternative in your DirectoryIndex directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /route.php
```

Quote from the documentation,

> Several URLs may be given, in which case the server will return the first one that it finds.

So it will first look for an `index.php` in the current directory, and if that does not exist, for the `/route.php` at the root level.